# using ng-if directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to write the following code using the ng-if directive insteade of ng-show?

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="storedata in storedata.data">
        <tr class="table_row_{{childItem}}">            
            <td class="table_col1" >
                <div ng-show="!storedata.hideButtons" class="btn-group  pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Edit" ng-click="openStore(storedata.storeId, storedata)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="New" ng-click="openStore(storedata.storeId)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </div>
            </td>
```

Comment: Yes... Have you tried it?

Comment: Should really be asking questions when there is a legitimate problem. This question doesn't imply any problems. If something isn't working then explain that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine, unless some other javascript code is explicitly relying on the buttons to be present to pass some custom validation.

`ng-show` merely hides the element using CSS.

`ng-if` completely removes the element from DOM.

`ng-if` is slower because modifying DOM requires more processing power. But it is useful when you have ie. form elements which you do not want to have their value appear in the result. Because a hidden element using `ng-show` will still be validated (and will cause a form to fail validation even if it's hidden), where if you use `ng-if` it won't be validated.

Comment: since ng-show is working good , I will stick to it , my app is already slow so no need to be slower , thanks